# windows 2012 r2 nic teaming does not aggregate bandwidth

Tags: nic, network-teaming

2 X Dell R730 boxes each with Dual 10G broadcom NIC. NetGear 10G 10BaseT switch. LACP set in switch. Boxes config with NIC Teaming (switch dependent, dynamic, all active).
- when I copy a file I get a nice 9Gb transfer but should be twice that
- used iperf (so file xfer) to test NIC and get same thing.
 - tried 2 instances on each box, with separate ports (same thing)
 - added second IP on destination box so client sent to 2 IPs on same box (same)
Question: should I be able to see double file transfer speeds? (yes,drives are fast enough-12G). Also, what is a proper setup/utility to b

Answer (score 2):

LACP does not necessary increase bandwidth! If there's only one TCP connection you'll get fault tolerance but no performance boost! See good story wrap up here:

http://www.hp.com/rnd/library/pdf/59692372.pdf

In your case you have to configure SMB Multichannel and in this case SMB redirector will push data over multiple independent "pipes" aka TCP connections on Round Robin basis. That's going to give you both fault tolerance *and* bandwidth increase. See here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn610980.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. Loadbalancing for Windows 2012(X) is file level and not packet level. If you transfer 1 large file you will only get 9-10GBp transfer speeds. Try and transfer many files totaling a large amount.
2. Try using switch independent mode instead of LACP regardless if you're switches support the configuration. This enables the logic of load balancing happen at the server level and you'll see bandwidth aggregation of 20GBps.

We have dual 1GBps NICs for 1600 franchisee servers and get 2GBps throughput and solid fault tolerance using switch independent teaming mode, Dynamic load balancing mode, and no standby (both active).